# Crashes not displayed in sulley fuzzing framework on fuzzer localhost:26000

Tags: fuzzing

Question: Is the sulley fuzz control supposed to update in real time?

background:
It apears that my procmon script is not recording crashes in the crashbin file. I have setup sulley fuzzing framework step by step with the install instructions however I am not able to see access violations within the fuzzer script output or the sulley web app. I am fuzzing a application given to me from a course and the application is crashing correctly. I have fuzzed multiple programs to test sulley and get many crashes however the debugger is not displaying access violations. I have sulley and paimei setup "perfectly" and can import all library's from each folder location and globally. here is a list of library's. My fuzz script is configured perfectly! All connections happen with all sulley scripts correctly and I get info, debug and warnings, I am using log level 10. My crashbin is not growing when the application crashes and I request any help to fix the issue.

scripts run on the fuzzed machine
python network_monitor.py -l 10 -d 0 -f "port 80" -P audits --port 26001
python process_monitor.py --port 26002 -l 10 -c audits/master_server.crashbin -p "application.exe"

pydasm,
pdbg
pcapy
impacket
sulley
tornado
flask
pedrpc

installation instructions
https://github.com/OpenRCE/sulley/wiki/Windows-Installation

[image]

[image]

following a guide I fuzzed the vulnserver LTER /.:AAA and below is an output of the PEDRPC results

[image]

Comment: I fixed half the soulution by correcting a simple mistake. I changed my process_monitor.py script on the remote host fro 0.0.0.0 to my ip address. My steps below. 

1. I started fuzzing vulnserver.exe and confirmed a working walkthrough
2. I ran netstat -ano in order to look at ports 26001 and 26002
3. found that processmonitor was not connecting correctly.

Comment: working on the second issue, My crash bin is not recording correctly.

Comment: after todays work I am still not able to get sulley to debug the programs. The crashbin file will not grow.

Comment: I'm not sure about Sulley. You might try the more frequently updated [boofuzz](https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz/) (disclaimer: my project). I recall fixing a few things related to crash bins. As a heads up, the procmon connection interface changed recently and you may need to change your code a bit. Otherwise it's mostly compatible.

Comment: I moved to boofuzz and got it working with the procmon, When doing that I think there was issues with my syntax of my fuzzing script. I will probebly have a need for sully agian in the future and go back to see if it was my syntax of the fuzzing script. That being said I am really liking boofuzz right now. Thanks for the fix.